# Use of unresolved identifier 'section' in tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, undeclared-identifier

I am coding a tableview with users posts to display. I am currently trying to break it into to sections to where the first section consist of the posts by users and the second section consists of a spinner cell that loads more posts. I keep getting a small error in my code shown here. [image: Unresolved Error] If anyone can explain why I am getting this issue when I have never had this issue when running similar code. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `indexPath.section` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking but I think I still might be able to help. I am currently working on a project with a table view also. I would try creating a variable or some other data type that contains the specific cells you want to be in that section. I would use `indexPath.row` to add these cells to that variable. I would then try running an if statement with that variable that contains those specific cells and then running the code based on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
If indexPath.section == 0 {
...
}
```